# Извлечение текста из строки

Tags: php

```
$text="ываыпа12345abc0000";
```

вот есть такой текст, как вырезать из него abc - этот текст, если известно, середина (12345 - не меняется), и длина abc (3символа), но концовка может быть разная (тобишь не только 0000, но и текст и т.п.)

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*12345(.{3}).*$/s', '\1', $text);
```

получил ответ, код работает,  но проблема в том что начальные данные не 12345, а текст, который содержит символы, а именно ",',(,), и код выдает ошибку, как можно отредактировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*'.preg_quote('сюда скопируйте тот текст').'(.{3}).*$/s', '\1', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
preg_replace('/^.*[",\',\(,\),](.{3}).*$/s', '\2', $text);
```